# SSIS SQL Task: strange value for stored procedure output parameter with default value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis, default

Here's a simplified version of my sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddSomething
@i_input1 int,
@o_output1 int = 1 OUTPUT,
@o_output2 int = 2 OUTPUT
AS
-- Do stuff
```

If I don't explicitly set values for `@o_output1` or `@o_output2` within the sproc then I expect to see the default output values of 1 and 2.  It works this way when I call `EXEC usp_AddSomething ...` from a normal SQL script.  However, when I run the same statement in an SSIS SQL Task like so:

```
EXEC ? = usp_AddSomething
@i_input1 = ?,
@o_output1 = ? OUTPUT,
@o_output2 = ? OUTPUT
```

I get seemingly random values (e.g. 15305391 and 69085360) instead of the default 1 and 2.

But if the values are explicitly set somewhere in the sproc like so:

```
...
SELECT @o_output1 = 1
SELECT @o_output2 = 2
RETURN 0
```

Then I get the expected values of 1 and 2 in SSIS.

My SSIS vars are Int32, the Parameter Mapping on the SQL task uses LONG and the ordinal positions (i.e. 0, 1, 2) are setup correctly under Parameter Name.

It's easy enough to redundantly initialize the values of the output parameters to match their defaults, but I'd really like to know WHY it's not working.  Maybe another quirky SSIS thing?  SQL Server 2005 SP4.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to see what's going on is to start a trace with profiler and see the t-sql that ssis is sending to the database engine. Then try executing that from ssms and see if you get the same results.